# jquery getJSON request with params

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is my js script :

```
$.getJSON(riceviPaginaPrincipale, {tipo: "Principale"}).done(function(data) {
    $("#contenitorePaginePrincipali").empty();
    $.each(data.risultato, function(){
        $("#contenitorePaginePrincipali").append('<button class="btnMenu">'+this['Nome']+'</button>');
    });
    $("#contenitorePaginePrincipali").append('<button class="btnMenu" onclick="creaPagina()"> Crea nuova pagina </button>');
});
```

and this is my php script :

```
<?php
//It includes session script php and global variables
include('../../sessione.php');

$tipo = $_POST['tipo'];

if(!$conn){
    mysqli_close($conn);
    $_SESSION['error'] = "Connessione al database pagine fallita.";
}
else{
    $comando = "select * from Pagine where Tipo='$tipo'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $comando);
    $res = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {          
        array_push($res, array('Nome' => $row[2]));
    }
    $_SESSION['error'] = "Connessione al DataBase pagine riuscita, pagine recuperate.";
}
echo json_encode(array("risultato" => $res));
?>
```

but it doesn't work. I'm not receiving anything.

Comment: Which part doesn't work? The PHP or the JavaScript? What are your errors?

Comment: the php file i think... i do no have errors

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Your javascript will use get method. Your php looks for post parameters

Comment: try echoing out a hardcoded string just to see if it responses, if so then it's mostly the query of the db

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set("display_errors", 1);` to your PHP script to turn error reporting on.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently sending the server a GET request. Id imagine that this is then causing some error due to the lack of validation on the $tipo = $_POST['tipo'] line.

You should look into using the POST from jquery http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ and also ensure you validate your code

`if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { 
    // post handling 
}`

Is a basic starting point.

You should also be checking your query you are sending to MySQL its open to SQL Injection. Look into using http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php